# Using SqlDatabase for .NET, information_schema is not available in a new DB, why?

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a very simple that which will use an embedded local database. For that, I decided to use SqlDatabase (http://www.sqldatabase.net/, downloaded as a .NET Nuget)
The app needs to check first if the table structure exists and if it does not, create it. I thought I will simply check the information_schame but I am getting the error: NO SUCH TABLE. I thought it is always present?

```
connectionObject.ConnectionString = "SchemaName=db;datasource=file://c:\\TestApp\\db1.db;";
 commandObject.Connection = connectionObject;
                    commandObject.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'USERS';";
                    var result = commandObject.ExecuteScalar();
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: What db is it? Sqlite?

Comment: @shankalpesh It is http://www.sqldatabase.net/

Comment: [Here](http://www.sqldatabase.net/docs/create-table.aspx) it shows a syntax that you can use to check and create table if it does not exist. The syntax is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: `SELECT sqltext FROM SYS_OBJECTS Where type = 'table' AND tablename = 'TestTable' LIMIT 1` is the code I see on [this page(https://github.com/sqldatabase/embedded-dotnetcore20/blob/master/SQLDatabase.Net.Core.Examples/SQLDatabase.Net.Core.Examples/SQLExamples.cs)

Comment: "I thought it is always present?" - it is up to each database engine implementation to provide (or not) that API; if it isn't present, then presumably SqlDatabase.NET` *doesn't provide it*? It is simply a convention, not a hard requirement in any way. Heck, they could provide it but call it "THINGS_WOT_I_HAZ" - you'd need to check the documentation.